# Mysql database autoincreament id not increases in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have created one table in mysql phpmyadmin,and i gave autoincreament for "id" and created one more column for image which should not be same image for same id thats why i have changed it to unique.
now the problem is that id has autoincreamented but if i'll fire my insertion query it's inserted id number for exa:-1 to 10 and next time again i'll fire my query its insert id number like:-40 to 50 and now its taking directly 1000 to 1010 and so on. 
i'm using simple query:-

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into Wheel_Place_Images(place_image_url,creation_date,last_modification_date,status)values('$image_url','$date','$date','1')");
```

i can't understand what is the problem here.

Comment: Is `place_id` the unique id with auto increment?

Comment: yes Epodax,place_id is primary_key with auto increament.

Comment: If you use auto_increment, you don't need to insert the id itself - that will happen automatically. Isn't that what "place_I'd" is?

Comment: If this is a primary key, then you should not be relying on its value. It sounds like the auto-increment is working but getting gaps. If commands like _INSERT ... IGNORE DUPLICATE_ are used - these will always cause gaps when a duplicate is detected. You should also not be manually inserting the values - where do you get the value to add from ?

Comment: hey PaulF,actually i'm getting this images from the google api.

Comment: hey Qirel,i'm not inserting this place_id it's inserted automatically because of autoincreamented.

Comment: hay Paul..you told if commands like insert ignore or insert ignore duplicate,this will cause gaps when duplicate is detected,so can you tell me what is the solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset or set initial value to auto increment in MySQL using following code.

Use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Wheel_Place_Images` AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

or if you haven't already added an id column, also add it

```
ALTER TABLE `Wheel_Place_Images` ADD place_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD INDEX (place_id);
```

You don't need to insert `place_id` manually.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Wheel_Place_Images`
                     (place_image_url,creation_date,last_modification_date,status)
                     Values ('$image_url','$date','$date','1')");
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I have very simple trick to avoid gap in auto incremented ids.

Just get the max high value from id field then add 1 to it.

```
$row = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(place_id) AS `maxid` FROM `Wheel_Place_Images`");
if ($row) {
    $maxid = $row->maxid + 1; 
}
```

Then

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Wheel_Place_Images`
                     (place_id, place_image_url,creation_date,last_modification_date,status)
                     Values ('$maxid','$image_url','$date','$date','1')");
```

Comment: hey Hassan,thank you for reply,actually bymistakely i have wrote here,but actually its inserted automatically.i have updated my code just check now,sorry for mistake.

Comment: I accepted hassan..but do you have any solution for this??

Comment: @Neha you want to save same inserted id in `place_image_url` field?

Comment: No Hassan, in "place_image_url" ,here this field is unique and i have to insert image's url ,the problem is that place_id is auto increament ,it's taking gap numbers like 1 to 10 then directly 50 to 60 like this,it should be proper number no.

Comment: @Neha I have updated my answer. Please try it. I hope it will solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: Hey Hassan,Thank you for your effort .I will try your logic, it should be work.

Comment: Thanku so much Hassan..because of your logic ,now I understood what I have to do now..:-)

Comment: @Neha can I get your facebook id?

Comment: send me your id Hassan..I'll send you.